# How to enable TimePicker in SIlverlight 4 Toolkit?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, timepicker

According to the Silverlight Toolkit website they have a TimePicker as Preview available.

I have installed the toolkit but don't get to see it.  How do I activate the Preview controls like the TimePicker?

Many thanks,

Comment: You installed the toolkit, what assemblies are you referencing?  Also, you can install toolkit pieces from nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see the TimePicker in your Toolbox, right-click, select "Choose Items" and add it manually. If you don't find it there, this means that the toolkit assemblies aren't registered correctly. What you can do is add a reference to them in your solution and access the controls directly. TimePicker is in `System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit` namespace in System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1. For TimePicker control you need to reference the following dll:

   System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll
2. Next, add the following namespace to XAML:

   `xmlns:toolkitInput="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Window‌​s.Controls.Input.Toolkit"`
3. Now you can use the TimePicker control as:

   `<toolkitInput:TimePicker Value="{Binding Model.ExecutionFrequencyStartTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

Comment: For some reason the last line is not displayed: <toolkitInput:TimePicker Value="{Binding Model.ExecutionFrequencyStartTime, Mode=TwoWay}" />